# input string was not in a correct format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I m having problem which prompt me that error when i was trying to decrypt the message..below is my code..

```
Private Sub btndecrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndecrypt.Click
    Dim key As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtkey.Text) << THIS CODE GIVE ERROR**'input string was not in the correct format**

    decrypt(key)
    Txtmessage.Text = totaldecry

End Sub

Private Sub decrypt(ByVal key As Integer)
    Dim length As Integer

    length = Len(receivemsg)
    ReDim y(length)
    Dim chararray() As Char = receivemsg.ToCharArray
    For a As Integer = 0 To length - 1
        y(a) = Asc(chararray(a)) - key
    Next

    For a As Integer = 0 To length - 1
        totaldecry = totaldecry & Chr(y(a)).ToString 
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What you are doing is not encryption. At best it's a cypher. Look at the System.Security.Cryptography namespace for real encryption.

Comment: Besides what Joel said, what line exactly causes "prompt me that error"? You've posted code out of any context - please don't make us guess where the problem might be happening.

Comment: you're trying to decrypt a string and trying to parse to `Integer` but you have some string that`s not acceptable for `Integer` that's is why the error appeared :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: the text box didn't contain text that could be turned into an Integer value. If I enter my name into your textbox, how do you expect to get an integer out of that? You need to be able to deal with bad inputs. Either catch the exception or use TryParse() instead of the Parse() function. How you want to handle the failure is up to you.

And while we're at it, I hope you're not doing anything real with that "decryption" code... there's no real security there at all.

But if you must, I'd write the decrypt function like this:

```
Private Function decrypt(ByVal key As Integer, ByVal message As String) As String
    Return New String(message.Select(Function(c) Chr(Asc(c)-key)).ToArray())  
End Function
```

Just a one-liner. That's how "secure" your encryption is. You can use the function like this:

```
Private Sub btndecrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndecrypt.Click
    Try
        Txtmessage.Text = decrypt(Integer.Parse(txtkey.Text), receivemsg)
    Catch
        'do something here to let user know it's a bad key
    End Try
End Sub
```

Also notice I changed your function definition to reduce the reliance on global and class-level variables to pass information among functions. That's just better style.

Answer (score 0):

here's a link it might you check and hopefully it could give you some idea about your task :)[Encryption and Decryption of Password using VB.NET](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/30280-Encryption-Decryption-Password-using-VB-NET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Integer.Parse() function directly convert the value.  It is not testing the actual value and raise error if the parameter is not integer.

So you may use integer.TryParse as follows.
if Integer.TryParse(txtkey.Text,key) then
    'successfully converted the integer and the value is stored in key.
else
   'the txtkey.Text is not having any valid integer.  So 0 is stored in key.
end if

It is better to create a class that has all data type conversion functions and call the function from the class when required.  I created the following class for using in my code

--------------------------class in my code ------------------------------------

```
Public Class NullValue
    '''''''''''''''''' 1. BYTE type convertion
    Public Shared Function getByte(ByVal mValue As String) As Byte
        Dim mNumber As Byte
        If Byte.TryParse(mValue, mNumber) Then Return mNumber Else Return 0
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 2. Int16/Short Integer type convertion
    Public Shared Function getInt16(ByVal mValue As String) As Int16
        Dim mNumber As Int16
        If Int16.TryParse(mValue, mNumber) Then Return mNumber Else Return 0
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 3. Int32/Integer type convertion
    Public Shared Function getInteger(ByVal mValue As String) As Int32
        Dim mNumber As Int32
        If Int32.TryParse(mValue, mNumber) Then Return mNumber Else Return 0
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 4. Int64/Long Integer type convertion
    Public Shared Function getInt64(ByVal mValue As String) As Int64
        Dim mNumber As Int64
        If Int64.TryParse(mValue, mNumber) Then Return mNumber Else Return 0
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 5. Single type convertion
    Public Shared Function getSingle(ByVal mValue As String) As Single
        Dim mNumber As Single
        If Single.TryParse(mValue, mNumber) Then Return mNumber Else Return 0
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 6. Double type convertion
    Public Shared Function getDouble(ByVal mValue As String) As Double
        Dim mNumber As Double
        If Double.TryParse(mValue, mNumber) Then Return mNumber Else Return 0
    End Function


    '''''''''''''''''' 8. Integer(Int32 type convertion
    Public Shared Function getInt32(ByVal mValue As String) As Integer
        Dim mNumber As Int32
        If Int32.TryParse(mValue, mNumber) Then Return mNumber Else Return 0
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 9. Short Date type convertion to String '''in Regional format
    Public Shared Function getDateString(ByVal mValue As String) As String
        Dim mDate As Date, strDate As String = ""
        If Date.TryParse(mValue, mDate) Then
            strDate = Format(mDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")
        Else
            strDate = ""
        End If
        Return strDate
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 10. Short Date type convertion
    Public Shared Function getDate(ByVal mValue As String) As Date
        Dim mDate As Date
        Try
            Date.TryParse(mValue, mDate)
        Catch ex As Exception
            mDate = Date.MinValue
        End Try
        Return mDate
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 11. Short Date type convertion
    Public Shared Function getDateTime(ByVal mValue As String) As DateTime
        Dim mDate As DateTime
        Try
            Date.TryParse(mValue, mDate)
        Catch ex As Exception
            mDate = Date.MinValue
        End Try
        Return mDate
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 12. Short Date type convertion
    Public Shared Function getBoolean(ByVal mValue As String) As Boolean
        Dim mBool As Boolean
        If Boolean.TryParse(mValue, mBool) Then Return mBool Else Return False
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''' 11. Time Convertion
    Public Shared Function getTime(ByVal mValue As String) As String
        Dim mDate As DateTime, mTime As String = ""
        Try
            mDate = Convert.ToDateTime(mValue)
            If mDate.Year > 1950 Then mTime = mDate.ToShortTimeString
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return mTime
    End Function
End Class
```